# Use $q to execute a function AFTER a few other functions have been executed?

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

All of the tutorials about `$q.all()` that I can find involved creating `$q.defer()`s and passing them to an array of `promises` and then calling `$q.all(promies)`

My question is, what if I wanted a function to execute after some other functions were executed and resolved? For example, I want `D` to run after `A`, `B`, and `C` run?

But the key thing is, they are separate functions and not in the same block

For example:

```
var func1 = function(){
     var deferred = $q.defer();
     // do stuff
     if (successful){
         deferred.resolve("success");
     return deferred;
}
var func2 = function(){
     var deferred = $q.defer();
     // do stuff
     if (successful){
         deferred.resolve("success");
     return deferred;
}
var func3 = function(){
     var deferred = $q.defer();
     // do stuff
     if (successful){
         deferred.resolve("success");
     return deferred;
}

    var theMainFunction = function(){
        var promises = [];
        promises.push(func1);
        promises.push(func2);
        promises.push(func3);
        $q.all(promises).then(function(){
          //do cool stuff
        });
}
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Can you perhaps provide some code/pseudo code of how these functions are structured/where they're located?

Comment: @MathewBerg I added code which hopefully explains my predicament better

Comment: I did the same already with my own logic. I call all functions attach to the resolve event and count the number up of each promises which shall be returned.

Comment: If you just change promises.push(func1); to promises.push(func1()); for all functions it should do exactly what you are looking for (Right now you are waiting for the function object to be resolved. Since it is not a promise, it is resolved instantly.)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example given, you just have to change your "theMainFunction" slightly:

```
var func1 = function(){
     var deferred = $q.defer();
     // do stuff
     if (successful){
         deferred.resolve("success");
     return deferred;
}
var func2 = function(){
     var deferred = $q.defer();
     // do stuff
     if (successful){
         deferred.resolve("success");
     return deferred;
}
var func3 = function(){
     var deferred = $q.defer();
     // do stuff
     if (successful){
         deferred.resolve("success");
     return deferred;
}

var theMainFunction = function(){
    var promises = [];
    promises.push(func1().promise);
    promises.push(func2().promise);
    promises.push(func3().promise);
    $q.all(promises).then(function(){
      //do cool stuff
    });
}
```

Here's a jsFiddle with it working: http://jsfiddle.net/pc3p9yyz/

Answer (score -1):

Heres an example code, attach all promises, then execute them in a row, and wait for their return, if all returns were done, resolve your last one.

```
var deferred = $q.defer();

    var broadcastArr = [];


            broadcastArr.push(func);
            broadcastArr.push(func2);
            broadcastArr.push(func3);


    var broadcastPromises = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < broadcastArr.length; i++) {
        var returnedPromise = broadcastArr[i].callback();
        if (returnedPromise && returnedPromise.hasOwnProperty("then") === true) {

            //promise returned
            returnedPromise.then(function () {
                broadcastPromises += 1;
                if (broadcastPromises === broadcastArr.length) {
                    //All broadcasts recieved, callback now.
                    console.log("Broadcast finished");
                    deferred.resolve();
                }
            });
        } else {
            //No promise - count up
            broadcastPromises += 1;
            if (broadcastPromises === broadcastArr.length) {
                //All broadcasts recieved, callback now.
                //Maybe we just got no promises back, for take sure, do a timeout so we'll resolve.
                $timeout(function () {
                   console.log("Broadcast finished");
                    deferred.resolve();
                });
            }
        }
    }

    if (broadcastArr.length === 0) {
        //Reslove immediately
        $timeout(function () {

            console.log("No broadcasts attached");
            deferred.resolve();
        });
    }
    return deferred.promise;
```